# log4j: rotate log, when it's size exceeds defined threshold

Tags: java, logging, log4j

We have recently encountered a problem: if external service fails, logs easily become flooded with similar data indicating a problem. In *logback* problem was solved easily: I've set log size threshold, after which log files were rolled over and zipped.

Is there a similar feature, when using log4j? I need to have a support for both daily rollover and size-threshold rollover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hava a look at [RollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html). There is an example that you can base on. An appender for daily rolling is included. You can extend it if you need an additional size threshold, or use the [TimeAndSizeRollingAppender](http://www.simonsite.org.uk) from Simon Park.